# Why lua require won't search current directory?

Tags: lua, lua-5.3

say I've two files `test.lua` and `m.lua` in a folder, in `test.lua` as:

```
require("m")
```

then I run this file, howerver it raise an error:

```
lua: /Users/xx/works/scripts/test.lua:43: module 'm' not found:
    no field package.preload['m']
    no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.3/m.lua'
    no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.3/m/init.lua'
    no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.3/m.lua'
    no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.3/m/init.lua'
    no file './m.lua'
    no file './m/init.lua'
    no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.3/m.so'
    no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.3/loadall.so'
    no file './m.so'
```

As you can see the line `no file './m.lua'` appears but this is not true. `./m.lua` exists, and file permission stuff is OK. If I hardcode the path:

```
package.path = package.path..';'..'/Users/xx/works/scripts/?.lua'
require('m')
```

It will work as expected.

What should I do to make lua search current directory fisrt (like python's import) when require a module

Comment: `test.lua` and `m.lua` aren't in the current directory, are they?

Comment: Current directory is not the directory where your lua files are located.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current directory is the directory where you launch lua from.

The command line is missing in your example, if you used `lua test.lua` then it shoud work, if you used `lua works/scripts/test.lua` then it will not work.